# Error while importing SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

The below is the Log that i can see when building the SBT project.What is the below trying to say !

I'm using IntelliJ IDE and Scala 2.12 and SBT 1.0.3 to build the project.
I have verified the IDE Proxy settings ,its setup and works fine for other Build tools.
Is something missing my SBT installation ?? I tried accessing the failing links in the log and they too are throwing up with errors.

```
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=12805,suspend=n,server=y -server -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -Dhttp.proxyHost=THISISMYPROXYADDRESS -Dhttp.proxyPort=8090 -Didea.runid=2017.2 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" -jar C:\Users\USER\.IdeaIC2017.2\config\plugins\Scala\launcher\sbt-launch.jar idea-shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 12805
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\USER\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/USER/.sbt/1.0/plugins/}global-plugins...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443 (4182ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443 (4115ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): public: unable to get resource for org/apache/logging/log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443 (1036ms)
[warn]  Detected merged artifact: [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar):  (0ms).
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\USER\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\USER\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/USER/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[warn]  public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-structure-extractor-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[warn]  :: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[warn]  public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-idea-shell-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.jetbrains:sbt-structure-extractor:2017.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          org.jetbrains:sbt-idea-shell:2017.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.jetbrains:sbt-structure-extractor:2017.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\USER\.sbt\1.0\plugins\idea.sbt#L4-8)
[warn]            +- org.scala-sbt:global-plugins:0.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          org.jetbrains:sbt-idea-shell:2017.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\USER\.sbt\1.0\plugins\idea.sbt#L4-8)
[warn]            +- org.scala-sbt:global-plugins:0.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[error]         public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-structure-extractor-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[error]
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[error]         public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-idea-shell-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[error]
[error] download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:229)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? [error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[error]         public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-structure-extractor-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[error]
[error] unresolved dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/34.206.162.65:443
[error]         sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2017.2/ivys/ivy.xml: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/52.201.87.92:443
[error]         public: unable to get resource for org/jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/sbt-idea-shell_2.12_1.0/2017.2/sbt-idea-shell-2017.2.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443
[error]
[error] download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
```

**Update : Below is the file content**

build.sbt

name := "untitled3"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

**Update -- JAVA_OPTS setting**

SET "JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=sproxy.wwcorp.ad.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8090 -Dhttps.proxyHost=sproxy.wwcorp.ad.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8090"

**Update -- New Error log**

```
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\USER\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/USER/.sbt/1.0/plugins/}global-plugins...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.typesafe.com/52.201.87.92:443 (5372ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo.scala-sbt.org/34.206.162.65:443 (4118ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar): public: unable to get resource for org/apache/logging/log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.16.209:443 (1071ms)
[warn]  Detected merged artifact: [FAILED     ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar):  (0ms).
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/test-jars/log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\USER\.ivy2\local\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\USER\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\test-jars\log4j-core-tests.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/USER/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/log4j-core-2.8.1-tests.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:331)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:205)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:229)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:185)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:182)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:190)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:38)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:91)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:104)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:118)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2353)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.8.1!log4j-core.jar(test-jar)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

**Update SBT**

name := "untitled3"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

excludeDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j"

Comment: Hi, how could you fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, this had nothing to do with any proxies.  I had specified sbt.version=1.0.3 in project/build.properties, and I had installed sbt version 1.1.1.  The failure mode was baffling.

Answer (score 2):

For me this occured when upgrading scala 2.12.11 -> 2.13.2. It turned out I was using libraries, that did not support scala 2.13 at that time. My build.sbt looks like this (simplified):

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.11"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.0"
```

When using double percent, the artifact name gets a postfix with major and minor version of scala, for example `spark-core` is translated to `spark-core_2.12`. When I changed `scalaVersion` to 2.13.2, I would rely on dependencies with `_2.13` suffix, that did not exist (I checked on [maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12), that 2.12 is the newest scala supported.

Comment: That worked for me. In my case the dependency issue was caused by a plugin not supporting 2.13.

Comment: @mjuanes glad to hear that, consider upvoting the answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there's several things that've disappeared out of SBT's release cache that it needs for 0.13.x and for 1.x.x of SBT over the last couple of days.  Still looking for answers, I added a resolver for this out of Maven 2 that should be finding the thing (it is *DOWNLOADABLE* from Maven 2...) but it is ignoring the thing

I'm rapidly being very and deeply underwhelmed with sbt in the same manner as I am with Autotools (This is a very, very bad thing...).  Tools should be only as complex as they NEED to be and moderately straightforward in their use, regardless.  They should be *self contained* and not pull a bunch of stuff, willy-nilly, out of the aether like sbt seems to be wont to do.

I'll dig further myself and see if I can get it sorted out somehow and update answers accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the heap size to 5GB in sbt settings resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case launched sbt server affected reloading an sbt project. Shutdown the server helped me